# Curry-Skip Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I have to write a scheme function called curry-skip that recursively that returns the nth element of a list such that

```
(((curry-skip 1) 'foo) 'bar) => bar
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this recursively. I'm still fairly new to Scheme, so any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the following after looking at your example. It seemed fairly simple and as such I can't explain by what reasoning it came to be.

```
(define (curry-skip n) 
    (lambda (v) (if (= n 0) 
                    v 
                    (curry-skip (- n 1)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 3 cases here:

1. n>0  - you recurse down until n=0
2. n=0  - you memorize the argument, because that's the final value you need to return; memorization is done via a closure
3. else - ignore parameters until done, then finally return the memorized value

so

```
(define (res val)                                ; [procedure used for case 2 - n=0]
  (define (res0 . x) (if (null? x) val res0))    ; [case 3]
  res0)

(define (curry-skip n) 
  (cond
    ((< n 0) (error "n is negative"))
    ((= n 0) res)                                ; [case 2 - n = 0]
    (else    (lambda x (curry-skip (- n 1))))))  ; [case 1 - n > 0]
```

then

```
-> (((curry-skip 0) 'foo))
'foo
-> ((((curry-skip 0) 'foo) 'bar))
'foo
-> ((((curry-skip 1) 'foo) 'bar))
'bar
-> (((((curry-skip 0) 'foo) 'bar) 'baz))
'foo
-> (((((curry-skip 1) 'foo) 'bar) 'baz))
'bar
-> (((((curry-skip 2) 'foo) 'bar) 'baz))
'baz
```

Compared to your question my solution has got an extra pair of parentheses but that's as close as I could get.

Answer (score -2):

```
(define (curry-skip n)
  (if (zero? n)
      (lambda (x) x)
      (let ((rest (curry-skip (- n 1))))
        (lambda (x) rest))))
```

You want to compute the `(- n 1)` cases **outside** of the returned `lambda`!  So, in the above, when `n` is zero just return the one argument lambda; but, when `n` is positive, compute the `(- n 1)` case and return a lambda that ignores its argument and just returns the `rest`.

Note that, although not part of your question but related to a comment, if you needed a true curry, like in ML, you would need syntactic help as:

```
(define-syntax curry*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (a) body ...) (lambda (a) body ...))
    ((_ (a b ...) body ...)
     (lambda (a) (curry* (b ...) body ...)))))
```

Notice how the recursion creates lexical environments for each of `a, b, …` so that `body` can be properly evaluated.  The `curry-skip` doesn't have such a need.

Here is some code addressing the comment about doing the 'curry-skip' inside the returned lambda.  Doing the recursion outside of the `lambda` happens only once creating one closure; doing it inside the `lambda` creates closures on each invocation.

```
(define (curry-skip-o n)
  (if (zero? n)
      (lambda (x) x)
      (let ((rest (curry-skip-o (- n 1))))
        (lambda (x) rest))))

(define (curry-skip-i n)
  (if (zero? n)
      (lambda (x) x)
      (lambda (x) (curry-skip-i (- n 1)))))

(define (run skipper r n)
  (let ((f (skipper n)))
    ;; Repeat 'r' times with 'f'
    (let rep ((r r))
      (unless (zero? r)
        ;; Exhaust f
        (let rep ((i 0) (f f))
          (if (< i n)
              (rep (+ i 1) (f i))
              (f 0)))
        (rep (- r 1))))))

> (time (run curry-skip-o 10000 10000))            ;; create ~10^4 closures
running stats for (run curry-skip-o 10000 10000):
    no collections
    376 ms elapsed cpu time, including 0 ms collecting
    376 ms elapsed real time, including 0 ms collecting
    160032 bytes allocated
> (time (run curry-skip-i 10000 10000))            ;; create ~10^8 closures
running stats for (run curry-skip-i 10000 10000):
    191 collections
    1587 ms elapsed cpu time, including 965 ms collecting
    1588 ms elapsed real time, including 966 ms collecting
    1599840048 bytes allocated
```

Comment: Your definition is a nice contrast to the other one, but downvoted because the emphasized advice to compute the n-1 case outside is completely bogus.

Comment: Doing the recursion outside of the returned lambda avoids doing the remainder of the skips each and every time the lambda is invoked.  (Presumably it is invoked many more times than it is created.)  If it was a true 'curry' then it would need to be a) syntactic and b) lexically recursed.  I updated the answer with a true curry. (PS. Thanks for explaining the down-vote.)

Comment: no, that's still wrong.  Assuming a reasonable compiler, both would result in a very similar code and the same speed.  The only thing that is a tiny difference is doing the subtraction in or out of the function, but even that would be lifted by a good compiler anyway.  I don't know which implementation you've used, but by the obnoxious amount of allocation, it's most likely not compiling.  (Petite?  -- which is not compiling in its free version as a matter of principle.)  I used Racket 5.3.6, and you can see that the outside version is slightly slower: http://tmp.barzilay.org/sc.rkt

Comment: Ikarus Scheme.  I'm sorry, but that fact that you think that the two approaches would produce 'similar code' points to your lack of understanding of these two options.  Using a 'skip' argument of at most '3' means that the closure creation of the algorithm is lost in the noise.  Of course, if the scale of the problem is this small, then who cares - use the algorithm you want.

Comment: You've got that completely off...  Yes, closure creation takes a (very small) amount of time, but no -- not always, since a good compiler would eliminate the cost for small or for some identifiable forms; now, given that a function like that would normally be a bit faster with the inside version for small values and given that small values are most likely going to be more common, then from an optimization POV, you should prefer optimizing that case (hence using the inside version) since overall you'd win.

Comment: OTOH, the OP would most likely say that this is some homework and therefore optimizations are not a consideration -- and *that* is exactly why your advice is bogus: it promotes micro-optimizations where you should be thinking about the overall problem and try to get the simplest code.  I liked your answer since it was a demonstration of manipulating closures as values, but with the outside version even that is easy to lose.  This is why I firmly stand behind the bogos-advice claim.